# Global prefix to all routes for Sails.js application

Tags: node.js, routes, url-routing, sails.js

Does anyone know, hot to make global route prefix for sails.js application? I have changed prefix in config/blueprints.js, but sails still interacts socket.io using route without prefix.

E.g.:

Route is '/', prefix is '/prefix', when I'm trying to open mysite.loc/prefix/, sails sends request to mysite.loc/socket.io/1/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.10.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&t=1421833178234, as you see - without any prefix.

Are there any ways (without changing sails.js module code) to solve this problem?

Comment: Specifically, can I configure a multi-tenancy scenario directly in Node.js/Sails.js, or do I have to put an Apache in front, and run several Node.js instances behind?

Comment: @vsp, sorry, but I can't understand your question. Why do you want to do this? I think that anyway (one or several instances/tenancies), the situation will be the same.. I'm running simple scenario with one node.js instance, using nginx. Nginx rule is: "If prefix of requested url is /prefix then pass it to node process".

Comment: So maybe that is the correct pattern: put an Apache or nginx in front that does the routing?

Comment: @vsp, yeas, it is correct. There are no problems with server. I just wanted sails.js to send all requests, using the same prefix. Front-end, not back-end.